# Generating AST for BigQuery using ZetaSQL

Tags: google-bigquery, abstract-syntax-tree

I am new to ZetaSQL and trying to generate an AST for BigQuery *(sample query eg: select cols from dataset.table where condition;)* using ZetaSQL.

I have added below dependancy in my pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zetasql</groupId>
            <artifactId>zetasql-client</artifactId>
            <version>2022.02.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zetasql</groupId>
            <artifactId>zetasql-jni-channel</artifactId>
            <version>2022.02.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is how I am using Analyser to extract tables from query which works fine.

```
   String Querystr = "SELECT * FROM `projct_name`.dataset.table WHERE col='val';";
   List<List<String>> tables = Analyzer.extractTableNamesFromStatement(Querystr);
```

When I try to use **analyzeExpression** for same query, it is not able to parse the query.

```
   ResolvedNodes.ResolvedExpr resolvedExpr = Analyzer.analyzeExpression(Querystr, new AnalyzerOptions(), new SimpleCatalog("sample_catalog"));
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.zetasql.SqlException: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT [at 1:1]
    at com.google.zetasql.Analyzer.analyzeExpression(Analyzer.java:81)
    at SQL_Parser.main(SQL_Parser.java:43)
Caused by: com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT [at 1:1]
    at com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.google.zetasql.ZetaSqlLocalServiceGrpc$ZetaSqlLocalServiceBlockingStub.analyze(ZetaSqlLocalServiceGrpc.java:1506)
    at com.google.zetasql.Analyzer.analyzeExpression(Analyzer.java:79)
```

Similarly, If I try using **analyzeStatement** for same query, I am getting *Table not found* error.

```
    ResolvedNodes.ResolvedStatement resolvedStatement = Analyzer.analyzeStatement(Querystr, new AnalyzerOptions(), new SimpleCatalog("new_catalog"));
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.zetasql.SqlException: Table not found: projct_name.dataset.table [at 1:15]
    at com.google.zetasql.Analyzer.analyzeStatement(Analyzer.java:63)
    at SQL_Parser.main(SQL_Parser.java:49)
Caused by: com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Table not found: projct_name.dataset.table [at 1:15]
    at com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at com.google.zetasql.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.google.zetasql.ZetaSqlLocalServiceGrpc$ZetaSqlLocalServiceBlockingStub.analyze(ZetaSqlLocalServiceGrpc.java:1506)
    at com.google.zetasql.Analyzer.analyzeStatement(Analyzer.java:61)
```

It is not able to parse same query which worked fine when I tried extracting table names from the query. Query is pretty straightforward.
Am I using above functions provided by ZetaSQL Analyser correctly?
Is there any example explaining usage of it to generate AST?

Answer (score 1):

When ZetaSQL analyzes a statement, it doesn't only parse the query. It also performs certain validations while building the AST.

When analyzing a statement, all the tables referenced in it need to exist in the catalog. On your example, you are providing an empty catalog. Because of that, ZetaSQL does not know the `project_name.dataset.table` exists and raises that error accordingly.

This is the simplest example for analyzing a query that reads `project_name.dataset.table`:

```java
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `project_name`.dataset.table WHERE col='val';";
    
    AnalyzerOptions options = new AnalyzerOptions();
    
    // Create our "master" catalog
    // You also need to register the built-in functions
    SimpleCatalog catalog = new SimpleCatalog("catalog");
    catalog.addZetaSQLFunctions(new ZetaSQLBuiltinFunctionOptions());
    
    // Create a catalog for the project and add it to the master catalog
    SimpleCatalog project = new SimpleCatalog("project_name");
    catalog.addSimpleCatalog(project);
    
    // Create a catalog for the dataset and add it to the project
    SimpleCatalog dataset = new SimpleCatalog("dataset");
    project.addSimpleCatalog(dataset);
    
    // Create our table and add it to the dataset
    List<SimpleColumn> columns = List.of(
        new SimpleColumn(
            "table",
            "col",
            TypeFactory.createSimpleType(ZetaSQLType.TypeKind.TYPE_STRING)
        )
    );
    SimpleTable table = new SimpleTable("table", columns);
    dataset.addSimpleTable(table);
    
    ResolvedNodes.ResolvedStatement statement = Analyzer.analyzeStatement(
        query, options, catalog
    );
```